# Custom GridView in Android (trying to copy WindowsMediaPlayer album layout)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to create a layout similar to the one used to show albums in Windows Media Player (see screenshot below).

I have found that:

- it is not possible to stuff gridviews inside listviews.
- it is also not possible having headers or categories inside gridviews.
- my worry in building the view dynamically is that we can have thousands of items in total (hundred of categories and hundred of items within each category). So I think building a whole layout on activity/fragment creation is out of question.

Is my only possibility to develop a custom widget? Has anybody managed to get something like this running?

PS: I am targetting Honeycomb if it helps.

[image]

Comment: [this](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) may help.

Comment: Except this question is older than the other one you mention...